# How to fix access denied error for aks kubernetes commands?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

with service principal logged in with azure cli. Below command got this error.

```
az aks command invoke --resource-group rg-licanltcs-aks-prod --name aks-licanltcs-prod-eastus --command "kubectl create namespace testing"
```

> Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces "testing" is forbidden: User
> "db6023d1-75df-444d-ac2a-10c16a090fcc" cannot delete resource
> "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "testing"

Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin access is already provided to it.

[image: permissions provided]